# ImportError: No module named web3 in Django

Tags: python, django, ethereum, importerror, web3py

I'm trying to set up a wallet on Django, but I keep getting this error:

> ImportError: No module named web3

this is how I call it:

from web3 import Web3

(also tried import web3)

Comment: Is it this https://github.com/atereshkin/django-web3-auth? If it is, to call the module is not `web3auth`?

Comment: I'm assuming that import is happening somewhere in your django app's code, so: where is django installed? You'll need to install that `web3` module in the same python environment as django is.

Comment: i was using web3.py, but i found a solution! i needed to create virtual env to do their installs and signed in on my github through terminal to download their packages off the github website

Answer (score 0):

If you install web3 and put it into the same directory as your python file that should work since it's a non-native library.

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/40350/how-to-solve-importerror-no-module-named-web3

Comment: i found the solution, web3 only supports certian versions of python ( >3.x ) I was using 2.7. Thanks though.